# Intermittent ASP.Net State Service Error

Tags: asp.net, .net, session, iis

We are hosting an ASP.net website on a virtual machine. the ASP.net Session state service is running. However, we get the following exception every once and a while:

> Message: Unable to make the session state request to the session state
>   server. Please ensure that the ASP.NET State service is started and
>   that the client and server ports are the same.  If the server is on a
>   remote machine, please ensure that it accepts remote requests by
>   checking the value of
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\aspnet_state\Parameters\AllowRemoteConnection.
>   If the server is on the local machine, and if the before mentioned
>   registry value does not exist or is set to 0, then the state server
>   connection string must use either 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' as the
>   server name.

I have verified that the session state service is running, and it is trying to connect to local host:

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" 
stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" timeout="100"/>
```

In my research I came across the following forum post:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1409990.aspx

But there wasn't any resolution about this issue, other than trying to run session state in SQL mode.

**TL;DR:** Getting Session state service errors saying the service is not responding, even though the service is running on the same machine.

Comment: Is it only me, or in the last week we had at least half dozen of questions like this one?

Comment: When I looked for this question, there were a bunch from people who's service was actually off, and all they needed to do was turn it on. this is a different problem

Comment: It's not necessary a different problem if it was running and crashed! Mine is crashing for some reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a LOT of debugging, I found that one of our developers had attempted to improve view state performance by saving it into the session for two particular pages. When the user reached around 20 different sets of view state, the session service became overloaded, and started to flake out.

I have modified the page to no longer require view state, and this exception has not occurred.

Answer (score 2):

Check if your session state provider executable path is set properly, try different ones (from .NET 2.0 to 4.0 or vice versa). Last week we have patched our servers with Microsoft updates and one of side effects was a silent change of executable of ASP.NET Session State service from `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_state.exe` to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_state.exe` and we have such errors also. You can check it in Windows Services console.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with this setting, where is this listed? Is this executable path listed in the machine.config? in an app config for the service?

Comment: It is available under Services console, you can run it through _Start > Run_, typing in `services.msc`. Then select ASP.NET Session State service and check its properties.

Comment: ah, thanks. I am running in 4.0. I am trying to replace with 2.0 now.

Comment: Thank you Konrad, I really appreciate your help on looking into this. I was able to find more significant articles that helped me identify my issue.